# Don't wait for whole page to finish loading to output loop results

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that contains a loop like that:

```
<?php
foreach(range(1,50) as $index) {
   echo $index;
}
?>
```

This should output

```
1
2
3
4
5
... to 50
```

On my previous web hosting provider, it outputed them like 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5, etc.

But I moved to a new web hosting provider and now the browser doesn't display them one by one like my previous web hosting provider, but it waits for the whole PHP script to finish loading then it outputs them in **one time**.

Is it possible to make my new web hosting provider like my previous one? I don't want the whole script to finish loading then output them in one time.

Is it something in `php.ini` ?

**EDIT**: This is my try on using `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush` :

```
<?php
ob_start();
foreach(range(1,50) as $index) {
   echo $index;
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

But still same.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: You could play with `ob_flush` and related functions

Comment: Forgive me if I'm completely wrong, isn't that way the PHP works? It executes the code on page load when you request the page. Example here https://www.tehplayground.com/SbPOf48VFJhwNAt4

Comment: Sorry I forgot my attempt on using the `ob_` functions .. I added it.

Comment: @swonder - My loop actually doesn't output numbers, it does HTTP requests to an API so it takes time and I want the finished loop iterations to be displayed, not to wait for the other loop iterations to finish then display them together.

Comment: It depends on how PHP is configured with the web server,  this really isn't a programming related question, it's more of a system administration question as there are many many configuration options that prevent flushing including but not limited to PHP's output buffering, the fastcgi module's buffering, gzip compression, and more.

Comment: The ability to do this with PHP is very sketchy because the buffer functions can be overwritten by 1) the php.ini settings, 2) the web server, 3) the browser.  If you really need something to update in the browser in real time, in response to something happening on the server, the best place for that code is in the browser itself - i.e., JavaScript + asynchronous polling.